# how to save events ami asterisk in DB

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I used Asterisk PBX (Yeastar) s100 series .
I need to save events with AMI in DB .
It does not matter what the database is.
Is there a solution under php?

How do I do that?

Comment: Plz provide [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Phpami package + mysql-json should be enought for this task.

https://marcelog.github.io/articles/pami_introduction_tutorial_how_to_install.html

You also have CEL events, which is much simpler to get in db.
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242932